# function called multiple times when i select option from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

when i select option from select list function is called many times.. dont know why this happens...
data is comming from api and also drop down list categorys also comming from api....
why function is called multiple time when i select option from drop down menu

i can't post all code here because of stackoverflow rules

```js
var cardContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
var selectList = document.getElementById("select_list");

var apiLink = "https://api_link_here";
function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

function loadData(indexs = 0) {
  fetch(apiLink)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }
    })

    .then((resData) => {
      console.log(resData);
      category = resData.categories;

      data = resData.websites[`${indexs}`];
      // console.log(data);
      //  drop down list
      for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
        var optionList = new Option(category[i], category[i]);
        selectList.appendChild(optionList);
        // if (category[i] === "UI Graphics") {
        //   optionList.selected = true;

        // }
      }

      // drop down list click listner
      selectList.addEventListener("change", function () {
        cardContainer.innerHTML = "";
        selectedItem = selectList.selectedIndex;
        // indexs = selectedItem;
        loadData(selectedItem);
        console.log(indexs);
      });

      // for each start
      data.forEach((element) => {
        // card
        const card = createNode("div");
        card.setAttribute("class", "card");

        // card title
        const cardTitle = createNode("div");
        cardTitle.setAttribute("class", "card_title");
        const h4 = createNode("h4");
        h4.textContent = element.title;

        // card discription
        const cardDiscription = createNode("div");
        cardDiscription.setAttribute("class", "card_discription");
        const p = createNode("p");
        // element.description = element.description.substring(0, 70);
        p.textContent = element.description;

        // card logo
        const cardLogo = createNode("div");
        cardLogo.setAttribute("class", "card_logo");
        const img = createNode("img");
        img.src = element.logo || "aseets/404.png";
        img.onerror = function () {
          // error handling if image not found
          this.onerror = null;
          this.src = "aseets/404.png";
        };
        // resouce link
        const resouceLink = createNode("div");
        resouceLink.setAttribute("class", "resouce_link");
        const card_link = createNode("a");
        card_link.href = element.link;
        card_link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        const i = createNode("i");
        i.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-external-link");

        //append
        cardContainer.appendChild(card);
        card.appendChild(cardTitle);
        cardTitle.appendChild(h4);
        card.appendChild(cardDiscription);
        cardDiscription.appendChild(p);
        card.appendChild(cardLogo);
        cardLogo.appendChild(img);
        card.appendChild(resouceLink);
        resouceLink.appendChild(card_link);
        card_link.appendChild(i);
      });
      // for each end
    });
}
loadData();
```

Comment: You've created a code snippet which is good, but it doesn't seem to be reproducing the issue you mention. Can you please edit it to reproduce your error?

Comment: i cant post all code because of stackoverflow rules

Comment: usually, you don't need to post the entire code, only a small portion which is enough to reproduce your issue. Here is a link on how you can create a [mre]

Comment: You probably don't want to call `selectList.addEventListener` every time you get a response from your `fetch`. You're going to add multiple events.

Comment: check now updated full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code provided there is one issue which explains the behaviour you are seeing:

Within `function loadData` you are adding an event listener to an element:

`selectList.addEventListener("change"`

within this event listener you are calling `loadData` again. Which again adds an event listener.

So now you have 2 event listener applied to that element which are calling the `loadData` function. This will go on as long as you are triggering the event.

Put your event listener outside of your `loadData` function

```js
var cardContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
var selectList = document.getElementById("select_list");

var apiLink = "https://api_link_here";

function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

function loadData(indexs = 0) {
  fetch(apiLink)
    .then((response) => {
      // get the response
    })
    .then((resData) => {
      //Whatever else you are doing here
    });
}
selectList.addEventListener("change", function() {
  cardContainer.innerHTML = "";
  selectedItem = selectList.selectedIndex;
  loadData(selectedItem);
});
loadData();
```

```html
<div class="drop_down">
  <select id="select_list" class="list">
  </select>
</div>
```